# Matrix/array multiplication in R data frame

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to to do a matrix multiplication from a data frame in R.
The multiplication is such a way that 1st array is all elements from each column from data frame (1x6). Then we multiply it with a correlation matrix (6x6) and again with a transpose of 1st array (6x1) to give a final result. This has to be done on all rows of a data frame

here is the image of how i do it in excel

[snapshot of calculation in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcnQs.png)

```
A <- c(2,3,4,5,6)
   B <- c(4,5,6,7,8)
   C <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
   D <- c(8,9,10,11,12)
   E <- c(10,11,12,13,14)
   F <- c(12,13,14,15,16)

   df <- data.frame (A,B,C,D,E,F)

   ## 6x6 correlation matrix 

    corr <- matrix(       
        c(1,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,1,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,1,.6,.6,.5,
          0,0,.6,1,.6,.7,
          0,0,.6,.6,1,.6,
          0,0,.5,.7,.6,1),
          nrow = 6,ncol =6, byrow = TRUE)
```

What i need is to add another col in df with result for row 1 =   [2,4,6,8,10,12]* corr * transpose[2,4,6,8,10,12]

Answer (score 2):

The following one-liner solves it.
Note that in R vectors are column vectors so the transpose is on the left side of the multiplication.

```r
apply(df, 1, \(x) t(x) %*% corr %*% x)
#> [1]  940.0 1167.2 1420.8 1700.8 2007.2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>